# WorkManager dont restart after google play update

Tags: java, android

My app has a service and 3 PeriodicWorkRequest (running at 30,60 and 75 minutes) and after run update (via google play - internal version) or via "adb install -r package.apk" command, the service reopen (and run correctly), but worker is called, but i think they don't run.

How I check if worker is called and correctly enqueued?